# Question about disputed NAA-flag

Tags: support, not-an-answer

I flagged this post as "Not an answer":

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50060/276052

Which, to me, clearly looks like an attempt to reply to a now deleted [answer by @erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47727/276052):

1. It starts with "@ericksson ..."
2. The whole answer indeed fits very well as a comment to the now deleted answer by @erickson.
3. Nothing in the answer seems to be an attempt to answer the original question
4. The poster (Tom Hawtin) already has another answer (the accepted answer in fact) which is a very elaborative answer to the original question.

Yet the not-an-answer flag was disputed.

Am I missing something? Was it wrong to flag this post as NAA? If so, why?

Comment: As for why your flag was disputed its because 3 people unanimously reviewed it as "looks ok" in the LQP queue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13456805). So no moderator looked at your flag even.

Comment: I agree, it's a comment posted as an answer - so it's NAA. Looks like that answer dated from before there was a commenting feature.

Comment: Can the flag be re-raised or will it forever be recorded as an erroneous flag by me?

Comment: @CodyGray err perhaps I completely misunderstand but... the post already has a comment from 2008, the same day as the answer. Did you mean a tagging feature?

Comment: @CodyGray, not actively digging. Just stumbled across this question when reading on that page. Besides, would it be anything wrong with looking for old posts and flagging them if it's of poor quality (such as this one)?

Comment: @aioobe: Your flag will forever be recorded as disputed, even if the answer gets deleted later. However, as far as I know, disputed flags don't have any negative effect for you.

Comment: No, I meant a comment feature. You're right, though; apparently by this point in 2008, comments had been introduced, since someone left one. If you look hard, you'll find a number of old questions that (ab)use answers to leave comments because the comment feature had not been implemented yet. Flagging these is largely a waste of time, although that viewpoint doesn't please the more obsessive members of Meta.

Comment: I've never looked under the hood before into the moderation aspect of stackoverflow...  In a meta sense, how does a NAA flag effect search or display output?

Comment: NaA flags do not affect search or display output unless the answer gets deleted, in which case you will neither be able to search for it, or display it. @BenPen

Comment: Are you sure the flag is _disputed_ and not _declined_? Reading from [Meta.SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue): *if the number of (Recommend)Delete reviews is >= the number of Looks Good reviews, mark flags "disputed" [...]. Otherwise, mark flags "declined".* A unanimous "Looks OK" review [as pointed out by @Magisch](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333227/question-about-disputed-naa-flag?cb=1#comment387842_333227) (so number of Recommend Delete = 0) should decline the flag.

Comment: @Tunaki, [yep, it's disputed](http://imgur.com/a/GPo6p).

Comment: Weird, maybe something changed since that Meta post... Thanks @aioobe.

Comment: @CodyGray - I sometimes find flags on these useful, because we can then move comments to the post they're commenting on and clean up the question. Prevents people from having to hop around to follow what someone's saying. Not something I'd hunt for, but if you come across it I see no harm in flagging comments as answers. I'd just recommend using a custom flag and pointing out which post each answer needs to be a comment on, so we don't have to hunt around a large page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're right, this was a comment. I've removed it, since the post it was commenting on has been deleted.

I've also dealt with the reviewers involved.

In the future, for answers that could be good comments on another answer (not "me too", "I have a new question", etc. non-answers), I'd recommend using a custom flag and explaining which post they should be converted to a comment on. That's a quick decision for moderators to make, and only moderators can convert answers to comments in order to preserve them. Reviewers can only vote to delete (which would have still been a correct action here).

Comment: So... instead of flagging non-answers as non-answers, because reviewers might handle it incorrectly, we should use a custom moderator flag?

Comment: @TinyGiant - I'm saying that for the case where something might be a good comment (contains information useful for another post), and you'd want to preserve that comment, a custom moderator flag would be the only way to do that. Also, if it isn't immediately clear out of context that something is a comment and not an answer, "not an answer" flags may not be enough to convey that information. In the vast majority of non-answer cases, the answer doesn't warrant being kept and it's pretty clear that it's not an answer. I'm talking about the few that might require custom handling.